# Odoo 10: How to create project tasks from sale orders?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have set my odoo system according to the "User Doc" of [How to create tasks from sales orders?](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/10.0/project/advanced/so_to_task.html) and want to generate project tasks automating when a sale order containing "Service" type product was created.

However, it wasn't working even after I have tried severals times.

I didn't find the the "Track Service" item when I set up a "Service" product.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpBtZ.png)

Is this the reason which odoo system can't generate task automating? Or there some thing else cause the issue?

Anyone can give me some advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this answer will help to do your task in odoo version 10.

In order to get the track the `**Create Tasks From Sales Orders**` you follow the following steps.

### **Step : 1 Install the required applications / Configuration**

Install the 3 following app

```
 1. Sales Management  
 2. Project management  
 3. Time-sheet management
```

### **Step : 2 Create and set up a product**

**Note :**
Now in case to of the service product unit of the measurement is used in hours. to configure that go to

> Go to **Configuration -> Settings ->  Unit of measures -> check the
>   Some products may be sold/purchased in different unit of measures
>   (advanced) radio button)**

[image: 1-Config-UOM]

Now , create the product with following details

> To create the product Go to the **Sales -> Product -> Create**

```
 - Name: Service Contract 
 - Product Type: Service
 - Unit of Measure: Hours
```

as this all are the general setup shown on Image below

[image: 2-General-Product-Config]

Next configure **Track Service:**

> You will found this under **Sales -> Sales -> Product -> Invoice ->**
>   Select Create a task and track hours.

[image: 3-invoice-service-track-no]

> **Note :**
>
> - Link your task to an existing project or create a new one on the fly    if the product is specific to one project. Otherwise, you can
>     leave    it blank, odoo will then create a project per SO.
> - as your product is a service invocable by hours you have to set the    units of measures of the product to hours as well.

### **Step : 3 Create the Sales Order**

> Once the product is set up, you can create a quotation or a sale order
>   with the related product. **Once the quotation is confirmed and
>   transformed into a sale order, the task will be created.**

[image: 4-create-sales-order]

### **Step : 4 Access the task generated from the sale order**

> On the Project module, your new task will appear :
>
> - either on a related project if you have selected one in the product    form
> - either on a new project with the name of related the sale order as    title
>     (you can easily change the name of the project by clicking on More ->
>     Settings)

as shown in below image.

[image: 5-Project-task]

Answer (score 1):

The doc screenshot of the product form seems just wrong for Odoo 10. The track service option should be found in the page "Accounting" of a product. Maybe the module `sale_timesheet` has to be installed before.

Comment: I can confirm this to be the solution.  You will not see the "Track Service" options (in the invoice tab of the product) unless TimeSheets is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If the system configuration is not working, then try creating tasks as follows manually in your code by inheriting sale.order model

Iterate over your *order_line* one2many field of *sale.order* and check any products are of type service, if the condition is satisfied then invoke the create function of the model *project.task* and pass the field(of project.task model) values as arguments